# Making automatic updated date and time field in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, update, date, datetime

I want to make a date and time updated field as I edit an attribute field in this format `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00` (= `2016-05-08 11:04:00`) - my local date/time. The data is in a QGIS 2.14 shapefile and vector lines as screenshot below.

When a feature as `NULL` in the 'name' field, I want to enter a name for the road and the 'mod' field must receive de **mod**ified date/time like `'2016-05-08 15:16:00'`.

I already tried some options and failed.
I need help to start from beginning.

1. I create a new field, date/time type, but stays with `NULL` value after I edited, in the "name" field, or the feature itself.
2. I used too, the expression `now()`, but stays with `NULL` value after I edited.

**Note:** the date seen there, *`2016-04-14`* is the first value created with "Field Calculator".

[image]

I am using QGIS 2.14.

Comment: Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/192674/edit) your question to specify the data format and the versions of software in use. You should also specify the datatype of the target column (since date fields don't have formats)

Comment: Please ***edit the question*** to contain the requested information.  You should detail what you have tried, and **exactly** how it failed.  This will help allow our volunteers to understand what you are trying to achieve.  As it stands, there isn't enough information to more than guess at a solution -- I'm imagining an autopopulate column in DB2 *isn't* going to meet your needs.

Comment: Sounds to me if you would like to store the timestamp of the last edit/update of a feature in an attribute, did I get you right? Something like what ESRI calls 'editor tracking'?

Comment: Yes @JochenSchwarze, that´s what I want.

Comment: so what kind of data provider are you using (shape, postgis, ...) and by the way: is the 3-digit month a typing error or do you need something like 2016-may-08? perhaps catching the ´beforeCommitChanges´ signal of a ´QgsVectorLayer´ or an ´UPDATE´ trigger in postgesql might be successful.

Comment: A typing error: the format I want is yyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 (2016-05-08 11:04) - my local date/time. The data is in a QGIS 2.14 shapfile and Vector lines as screenshot above.

Comment: @Vince, pls see the edited question.

Comment: Shapefile is a miserable data format for timestamps, since dBase only supports day resolution (it doesn't really support NULLs either).  You need to use a character column for this information (which would then need to be parsed for any further use)

Comment: Let´s say I alter the content of the "name" field and It is impossible to have an auto updated date/time field to register the moment of a modified date in a shapfile, right? So, I just can use a text string type and edit it with the day and time at that moment. That´s it? I´m asking for something impossible!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following code which connects the `attributeValueChanged` event to a function we can define which inserts the results of the `$now` expression. Highlight your layer and copy/paste the following into the **Python Console**:

```py
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

def update():
    field = layer.fieldNameIndex('mod')
    e = QgsExpression( " $now " )
    e.prepare( layer.pendingFields() )
    for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
        feat[field] = e.evaluate( feat )
        layer.updateFeature( feat )

layer.attributeValueChanged.connect(update)
```

Select the feature by clicking the row number (shown in the red box in the image) or from the map canvas and edit **any** attribute for that feature. The attribute in your `mod` field should update:

[image: Result]

---

*Note: I used a **string field** instead of date in order to get the time, otherwise the date field only records YYYY-MM-DD*.

Comment: @CarlosPires - Most welcome! Hope it helps :)

Comment: so I created a new text string(20) field 'mod' **(see 1)**, I pasted your code into the Python console (after ctrl-alt-P), insert the name of the street 'name' **(see 2)**, left the record but the field is still NULL **(see 3)** as you see in the screen capture.  ![ScreenshotTry] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/lGR2D.png).

Comment: Now it works! As I am not a programmer did not know we had first run the code !! :( Sorry.

**Note**:It works with the select tool. If the attribute field is edited with the info tool (identify feature), it doesn´t work.

Comment: @CarlosPires - Glad you got it working (eventually!). Apologies, my fault, should have been more clear ;)

Comment: @CarlosPires You can use the [AutoFields](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) plugin for this. Watch [this video](https://vimeo.com/germap/autofields-time-stamp-for-feature-edits) for an example of automatic calculation of date and time. I guess it should also work if you use the identify tool to update your values, could you please check?

Comment: @GermánCarrillo, it seems a good choice. I will try later. Thanks.

Comment: Any way to edit the script to timestamp changes to the geometries? I have a large point shape and I want it to get a stamp if the point is moved. Is there a more elegant way than making a X an Y coördinate collumn which updates and triggers the code?

Comment: @HannesLedegen - I think you should ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: Is there any possibility to do that without selecting the row or to save the edits?

Comment: @Joseph - I just tried this in QGIS 3.4 and it looks like since the update fieldNameIndex has been renamed to lookupField. I tried renaming it but when I make an edit I get this error: "AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'lookupField'.

Do you know how to get this working in QGIS 3.4?

Thanks

Comment: @TeddyTedTed - You need to access the layer's fields first: `layer.fields().lookupField('fieldName')`

Comment: @joseph - I changed the line "field = layer.fieldNameIndex('fieldName')" to "layer.fields().lookupField('fieldName')", is that correct? Or does that line need to be inserted somewhere else? At the moment the error has changed to "AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'pendingFields'"

Comment: @TeddyTedTed - Could you post this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) please and include your code. That line should be correct so it may be an issue with how you are defining `layer`.

Comment: @Joseph - [Done](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304373/making-automatic-updated-date-and-time-field-in-qgis-new-question-for-qgis-3-4), thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this Q&A while I was looking for a way to date/time stamp changes I was making to records using a plugin. I placed a slightly modified version of the code into the plugin to automatically update the date/time into the record(s) I changed:

```py
""" Prepare Change Date/Time Stamp"""
e = QgsExpression( " $now " )
cDate = e.evaluate()

"""" Identify column(s) to change and new value(s) to assign"""
attrs = { 10 : newStat, 20 : cDate }

""" Make record change and capture date/time of change'''
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ fid : attrs })
```

Comment: Technically this seems not to be an answer but I think this "answer" may have some value to a future reader as part of the Q&A and so I am leaving it in place.  It needs more formatting than converting it to a comment would allow.  I'm happy to be overruled if anyone closer to writing QGIS Plug-ins than I am wants to make a case in comments here and then ping me or another moderator.

Answer (score 3):

I just selected `now()` function on default value expression and it worked.. very simple

I am using QGIS 3.14 PI

Just create a field with DateTime format and set default as now().

Right click on layer and select properties --> Attribute Forms-->select date field --> defaults--> Default Value Expression--> type now().

Apply and save.

Create new features and see. Timestamp will be updated into the field.