# What to do to keep Python code permanent in QGIS 2.14.2?

Tags: qgis, qgis-python-console

I have [this code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192674/how-to-make-a-automatic-updated-date-and-time-field-in-qgis-2-14) provided by @Joseph but lose it whenever I leave the QGIS and I have to load it on the Python Console whenever reopen QGIS.

What to do to keep this code in a permanent way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a project macro to execute python code whenever you open the project.

Navigate to File > Project properties > Macros and insert the code in the `openProject()` function.

```
def openProject():
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer('the_layer_id')

    def update():
        field = layer.fieldNameIndex('mod')
        e = QgsExpression( " $now " )
        e.prepare( layer.pendingFields() )
        for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
            feat[field] = e.evaluate( feat )
            layer.updateFeature( feat )

    layer.attributeValueChanged.connect(update)
```

You will have to replace 'the_layer_id' with the layer id in project.

You also need to make sure that Macros are executed `Always` in the application settings.

Comment: From where I copy the layer id?

Comment: Click the layer and evaluate `iface.activeLayer().id()` in the python console