# Is it possible to add the time of editing to the table of a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, time

I would like to automatically track the time when a point is created or edited.
I first thought about virtual fields and the now() function. However, that field always contains the current time. So maybe it would be possible to only update the virtual field one time, but I have no clue how. Is there a way or any other possibility to automatically track the time?

In contrast to the question [Making automatic updated date and time field in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192674/making-automatic-updated-date-and-time-field-in-qgis) or rather the answers I don't think it is reasonable to select a field or save the shapefile every time after editing a new feature. So yes the quesions may be similar, but the answers of the other question don't answer my question.

Comment: Perhaps that would be easier to do if you switch to GeoPackage and create triggers into the database for inserts and edits.

Comment: You mean something like this: [Making automatic updated date and time field in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192674/making-automatic-updated-date-and-time-field-in-qgis)

Comment: @Joseph not really, as the answer there updates the field every time a feature is selected and not when it is created (or changed).

Comment: You may want to look at the autofields plugin, I never use it but it seems to be able to do what you want

Comment: @Alex - The last line in the answer to the post I linked, you connect the function to a signal which is emitted by various actions. One of these is the [featureAdded](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac914dd316a4bb50eb432515950583806), so you could change `layer.attributeValueChanged.connect(update)` to `layer.featureAdded.connect(update)`. You can connect several signals to the function so maybe also when the geometry of a feature has changed: `layer.geometryChanged.connect(update)` etc.