# QGIS getting crashed on Update Feature Signal

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, editing, pyqgis-3

Like ArcGIS Editor Tracking, I am trying to design attribute field with self update date feature called Updated Date in QGIS. I am following [Making automatic updated date and time field in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/304373/142861) this link to get calculate it automatically but while doing so, the QGIS project is getting crashed every time. I am selecting only one feature but still it is getting crashed. I checked the code and it is running fine in Python console but not in Plugin. Please suggest.

Python Code for reference:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

def update():
    field = layer.fields().lookupField('fieldName')
    e = QgsExpression( " $now " )
    for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
        feat[field] = e.evaluate()
        layer.updateFeature( feat )

layer.attributeValueChanged.connect(update)
layer.geometryChanged.connect(update)
```

Comment: Have you tried the "Default value" functionality that comes out of the box with QGIS? https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/652785/39675159-c9aa93aa-511c-11e8-8d6d-a4cc14cc5332.png You can even set it programmatically.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo, I tried the way you mentioned with Python and it worked, Thank you!

Comment: Great! You can post the way you finally solved it, and even accept the answer, so that future visitors can also know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

While updating fields for Updated Features, first step is to read the fields like below,

```
update_date=vlayer.fields().indexFromName('updated_date')                
updated_user=vlayer.fields().indexFromName('updated_by')
```

After this, we can use the existing property of QGIS (`QgsDefaultValue`) in Python like written below,

```
vlayer.setDefaultValueDefinition(update_date, QgsDefaultValue('$now',True))
vlayer.setDefaultValueDefinition(updated_user, QgsDefaultValue("'{}'".format(str(uri.username())),True))
```

In the above expression it is necessary to mention True, to get to know about field update only on feature update. This is how QGIS stopped getting crashed.

Some other approaches are really appreciated.

Comment: That's the best approach. Single API method and you're done.