# QGIS (& QField) update entire column with 'survey end time'

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qfield

I have a QGIS project set up to be taken to site to gather data (likely on QField). There is a main point data layer where tube locations will be mapped. This is joined to a surveydata table that stores the information for the survey at each point as the tube will be surveyed many times over. I am trying to figure out how I can store the information for a start and end time for each survey visit without having to input it individually on every point.

The issue is that there is a possibility of more than one visit per day so I cannot simply enter the information once for the days surveys and copy it across. Is there a way to enter the start time on the first point and the end time on the last and have qfield or qgis fill in th epoints between these two?

Comment: Hi Nathan, this question is a possible duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192674/making-automatic-updated-date-and-time-field-in-qgis
Please check out if that works for you.