# QGIS Countdown timer

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, time, forms

Looking for a solution to implement a countdown timer that allows to report the column of a table with the time value at the same time that a new point geometry is entered. The idea would be to capture the time value in the geometry input form.

I have started investigating two already developed possibilities:

- Chronometro add-on: https://github.com/Korto19/Cronometro

It is a native window that shows the elapsed time with Start, Pause and Reset options, but without the possibility of capturing the time value.

- Field calc function: https://hfcqgis.opendatasicilia.it/esempi/cronometro/

This is a function that shows the elapsed time of a QGIS session. It also has no option to capture the time value in a table.

What I pretend is to be able to establish a timer with pause options and, that when introducing a new geometry captures the value of the timer. I add a screenshot of a simulation work flow (1.Enter point geometry → 2. Automatic capture time → 3. Insert time value in a colum table form.).

[image]

Comment: There is some time related code here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192674/making-automatic-updated-date-and-time-field-in-qgis

Comment: Thank you very much. These time-related answers are a good starting point. They show how to automate the capture of the time stamp. However, for my project, the key is to capture the specific time (minutes and seconds) of live countdown chronometer timer